# How to push from forEach in prototype to array in constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

If I have a global array like this

```
var arr = [value1, value2...];
```

I then got a construcotor like this

```
function myFunction() {
    this.array = [];
    this.toArray();
}
```

And then a prototype method like this

```
myFunction.prototype.toArray = function() {
    arr.forEach(function() {
        if (statement) {
        // How can I do if I from here, want to push the current value, to the array in the cunstructor function?
        }
    });
}
```

As the comment says, If I from where the comment is, want to push the current value in the forEach function back to the array in the constructor function? I tried with `this.array.push();` but realized I cant use this since it now refers to the arr array.

Comment: I suggest to [have a look at the documentation of `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), especially the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
If you don't like that `var that = this` in the snippet above you can do :

```
myFunction.prototype.toArray = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach((function(item) {
        if (item%2 ===0) {
           this.array.push(item);
        }
    }).bind(this));
}
```

But I do prefer :

```js
function myFunction() {
    this.array = [];
}

myFunction.prototype.toArray = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach((function(item) {
        if (item%2 ===0) {
           this.array.push(item);
        }
    }).bind(this));
}

var test = new myFunction();
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
test.toArray(arr);
alert(test.array);
```

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the object.

Comment: thats the problem, I get cant use push of undefined. I quess this is because the this keyword now reffers to the arr array and not the instance of myFunction?

Comment: @Alex sorry I answered too fast, i edited my answer with the correct solution and a snippet

Comment: Nice, thansk! But instead of using that, isnt it possible to pass down the this keyword as an parameter/argument?

Comment: @Alex : As far as I know, it's not. You could create your own forEach function but having a `var that = this` is common and is not a problem

Comment: @Alex edited my answer with the bind() solution in case you prefer it

Comment: Cant get it to work, but I dont know why...